# How does Django admin determine which fields are shown

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have 3 fields in my `Country` class in `models.py`. I then used the following code in `admin.py`:

```
from jobs.models import *
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Country)
admin.site.register(City)
```

After running `manage.py syncdb` I logged in to the admin and added a country. On saving it does not show proper name of the country but rather shows "Country Object" in list and drop downs where it is added as foreign key. How does Django determine which field should be shown in listing and select boxes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all depends on your `__unicode__` method. This defines what is displayed for each model instance in admin listings or foreign key links.

```
class Mymodel(Model)
    field1 = CharField()
    field3 = CharField()
    field3 = CharField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.field1

>>> Mymodel.objects.get(pk=1)
"contents of field1 that will show up for all related fields in admin"
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing `__unicode__` method of the model. this is the most simple way.

if you want more columns, you need to create a class inheriting from `ModelAdmin` and define the `list_display` property. Then you can link it like this:

```
admin.site.register(Country, CountryAdmin)
admin.site.register(City, CityAdmin)
```

you can find more details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).